# How can I handle the exception thrown by mongoskin if mongodb is not running?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongoskin to connect to mongodb from node but an exception is thrown when connecting if mongodb is not available and I can't seem to find a way to handle this.

My connection and query code look like this...

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var conn = 'localhost:27017/dbname'; 

mongo.db(conn).collection('collection').find({ date: { $gte: now } }, { sort: [['date', 1]]}).toArray(function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                callback(null, result)
            });
```

How should I deal with this?

Thanks, Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`throw err;` is useless here - there is no outer scope to catch the error since it is being called by the event loop as an asynchronous function. 
The convention in node.js is to fire a callback where the first arg contains an error (or null, if there is none), and the second arg contains the command result.

So you probably just want:

```
callback(err, result)
```

Or even just pass callback directly. In the code for your callback, check if err is null, and then handle the condition there.

Comment: Thanks, this is spot on!  I am just learning node and had copied and pasted this line from somewhere... I had assumed that express would catch and handle this for me but I understand now.